# Tutorials for the neural network tool in Matlab 7.0.4

Tags: matlab

Can someone please provide me with links to tutorials on how to use the GUI neural network tool called "nntool" in MATLAB 7.0.4 on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your looking to do, hopefully [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/54929963/9/Using-%E2%80%9Cnntool%E2%80%9DGUI) will help.